# fdisk doesnt not show other partitions on Linux OpenWRT

Tags: mount, partition, fdisk

I'm developing on an embedded Linux OS (FriendlyWRT derived from https://openwrt.org/) and we require a near full-proof recovery strategy, in case OTA updates dont work or corrupt the device, so we can revert to the last working OS image (factory image) on the embedded device.

**So I decide to use "dual copy" strategy, see** (https://mkrak.org/2018/01/10/updating-embedded-linux-devices-part1/).

Our OS runs on an SD similar to RasperryPi.

**I partitioned the 64 Gbyte SD card into 3 partitions:**

partition 1 - Active OS (~ 29 Gb)

partition 2 - Inactive OS (future update OS will be loaded) (~ 29 Gb)

partition 3 - Data (shared persistent non-OS dependent area). (~ 2 Gb)

All partitions are FAT32.

I created 3 partitions using 3rd party tool (EaseUS Partition Master 15.0) and Im able to see all partitions 3 partitions using "Win32 Disk Imager", I also burned OpenWRT to the 1st partition using "Win32 Disk Imager", see below snaphot:

[image]

**When I SSH over Wifi to the linux box & run** `fdisk -l` , **I get** :

```
root@FriendlyWrt:/# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/ram0: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram1: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram2: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram3: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram4: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram5: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram6: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram7: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 59.49 GiB, 63864569856 bytes, 124735488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7fe1e74c

Device         Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1       196608  1515519  1318912  644M 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p2      1515520 31116287 29600768 14.1G 83 Linux
```

fdisk shows bunch of small 4096 bytes partitions, then the entire  **Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 59.49 GiB**, and also **/dev/mmcblk0p1**  & **/dev/mmcblk0p2**  were the OS resides, however Im expecting the Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 59.49 GiB, to be partitioned into 3 parts, rather 1 giant 59.49 GiB.

**I need a way to:**

**1)I need a way to see and access the 3 other partitions.**

**2) The ultimate goal is  to change the boot order from partition 1 to 2, in case of OS update, or revert from partition 2 back to partition 1 in case of a bad update.**

I also tried using `lsblk` or `parted` or `blkid` to view partitions however, those programs are not available on the OS (FriendlyWRT) and `fdisk` doesn't show the other partitions.

**I understand that those partitions are may not be mounted, but how can I mount something I can't see???**

Appreciated & thanks a million!

Comment: It is hard to tell what went wrong. Fdisk is a tried-and-tested program, so I would say if fdisk says the partitions are not there, then they simply aren't, or there is something wrong with them, causing fdisk to not recognise them. You will need to go back to the partitioning step and check what went wrong, and possibly use some other program for the task.

Comment: @JohanMyréen, I added snapshot of the partition program that confirms the partitions, also "Win32 Disk Imager" which is another program shows the 3 partitions as D,E,F. Therefore 2 unrelated programs are showing the 3 partitions. I think this has something to do with the non-OS partitions NOT being mounted.

Comment: Do you see the partitions with EaseUS Partition Master also *after* writing the OpenWRT image to the first partition?

Comment: @JohanMyréen, I can no longer see the partitions after righting the image using WinDisk or balenaEtcher. However using "unetbooting" software the partitions are untouched, but the OS image wont boot.

Comment: I suspect the disk image is intended to be installed on the whole disk (or flash card), and contains a partition table of its own, overwriting the partitions you created. You may need to rethink your strategy and install a common boot partition which starts the OS from either of the OS partitions.

Comment: @JohanMyréen, as I mentioned I was able to overcome the initial problem of partition being overwritten. Now I have 3 partitions, and image is written correctly to the 1st partition, but OS wont boot? The same OS images either Ubuntu or FriendlyWRT only boot on single partition? This is odd as I have also had OS with many partitions. I want to avoid creating 1 partition then later using fdisk to resize at runtime. I want 3 partitions from the beginning. Is there a tool that creates multipartition drives and one can select a boot drive? Seems the OS should automatocally boot on 1st partirion?

Comment: Like I said, your image file is probably intended to be installed on the whole disk, not on a partition. It contains a partition table and two partitions. The partition you installed the image on now contains a partition table at the start, but the table is not useful there.

Comment: @JohanMyréen, so is there a way to create a ISO image of the OS that supports multiple partitions?